# Small, inexpensive offline device with camera for storing secure information

Tags: security

I'm looking for a small device (smartphone, netbook etc) to store passwords and other sensitive information. The device never goes online and has to be password-or PIN-protected. The device will be used only infrequently. Other requirements:

- small (ideally not larger than a iPad mini)
- has a hardware QWERTY keyboard
- has a camera
- storage space ist not important, as long as it fits ca. 100 photos and max 1 MB of text
- has an app for taking notes
- ideally with encrypted storage
- costs less than 100 USD/Euro used on Ebay, but preferably less, of course
- makes easy to transfer information out of the device without using an online or cloud solution
- is not a Chinese no-name device

Comment: I love the last requirement (rofl)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify operating system, but the [LG Extravert 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RC7B7DI) meets all requirements.  Just take the SIM card out.  Has camera.  Has SD Card for exporting data.  Has Qwerty keyboard.  Is small.  Is less than $100.  Is not no name Chinese.  Has an app for notes. Is PIN protected. Not sure about encryption,  but there's probably an Android app for that.

[image]